# Windows - I have an issue in selecting specfic column outputs using for /f command in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, patch, windows-server

I am trying to get the list of all KB installed in windows. I use the below command.

```
C:\Windows>wmic qfe list
Caption                                     CSName        Description      FixComments  HotFixID   InstallDate  InstalledBy          InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4514366  xxxx-LAP  Update                        KB4514366               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/23/2019
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4480056  xxxx-LAP  Update                        KB4480056               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/6/2019
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4512577  xxxx-LAP  Security Update               KB4512577               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/23/2019
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4512937  xxxx-LAP  Security Update               KB4512937               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/13/2019
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4516115  xxxx-LAP  Security Update               KB4516115               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/23/2019
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4521862  xxxx-LAP  Security Update               KB4521862               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/20/2019
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4519338  xxxx-LAP  Security Update               KB4519338               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/20/2019
```

From the above output i am interested in only "HotFixID" and "InstalledOn" column outputs. I don't need the rest.

I am using the below command , but the output is not proper as it doesn't ignore the space for columns.

```
C:\Windows>for /f "tokens=5,8" %i in ('wmic qfe list ^| findstr /v "Caption"') do @echo HotFixID = %i, InstalledOn = %j
HotFixID = NT, InstalledOn =
HotFixID = NT, InstalledOn =
HotFixID = KB4512577, InstalledOn = 9/23/2019
HotFixID = KB4512937, InstalledOn = 9/13/2019
HotFixID = KB4516115, InstalledOn = 9/23/2019
HotFixID = KB4521862, InstalledOn = 10/20/2019
HotFixID = KB4519338, InstalledOn = 10/20/2019
```

What command do I need which can give me only the outputs of "HotFixID" and "InstalledOn" in the above format?

Thanks.

Comment: The command that i use is C:\Windows>for /f "tokens=5,8" %i in ('wmic qfe list ^| findstr /v "Caption"') do @echo HotFixID = %i, InstalledOn = %j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wmic` can filter for the desired data on it's own.
(first token is always `Node`, therefore we take `tokens=2,3`)
(Header is skipped bye `skip=2`)

The important trick here is to use `/format:csv` to get a comma as separator (so we tokenize without caring of any spaces)

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in ('wmic qfe get HotFixID^,InstalledOn /format:csv') do echo "HotFixID = %%a, InstalledOn = %%b
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get the required output with the above command.